# Django : Getting attribute during making JSON for Rest-API?

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I want to create the JSON Rest-API, but during the creation I am getting the attribute error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'`. In following code `api.nova.server_list(self.request)` return the list of instances. Now I want to make JSON data only name of instance and id. But I am getting Attribute error.

**Django code for creating JSON Rest-api**

```
    class InstanceList(django.views.generic.View):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
              instances=api.nova.server_list(self.request)
              def serializer(m):
                  ret= {}               
                  ret['Name']= m.name
                  ret['Id']=m.id
              context= {
                  'instances': [serializer(m) for m in instances],
              }
              return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')

**AttributeError at /admin/metering/project/**

    ([
    <Server: {
        'status': u'ACTIVE',
        'OS-EXT-STS: task_state': None,
        'addresses': {
            u'private': [
                {
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS-MAC: mac_addr': u'fa: 16: 3e: 85: 98: 6a',
                    u'version': 4,
                    u'addr': u'192.0.0.6',
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS: type': u'fixed'
                }
            ]
        },
        'name': u'test2',
        'links': [
            {
                u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/v2/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/servers/7a3a2eab-7d3b-498b-bc69-ba39396ada4f',
                u'rel': u'self'
            },
            {
                u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/servers/7a3a2eab-7d3b-498b-bc69-ba39396ada4f',
                u'rel': u'bookmark'
            }
        ],
        'created': u'2015-08-03T07: 58: 09Z',
        'key_name': None,
        'image': {
            u'id': u'd983bdc9-9a82-4611-b644-86f9bf53406b',
            u'links': [
                {
                    u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/images/d983bdc9-9a82-4611-b644-86f9bf53406b',
                    u'rel': u'bookmark'
                }
            ]
        },
        'OS-DCF: diskConfig': u'AUTO',
        'image_name': u'cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-uec',
        'OS-EXT-STS: power_state': 1,
        'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR: host': u'localhost.localdomain',
        'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR: instance_name': u'instance-00000005',
        'tenant_id': u'020377f522324546b072af92862e6466',
        'user_id': u'f807d60e53c9454ebe7b38d10d1d1c87',
        'flavor': {
            u'id': u'42',
            u'links': [
                {
                    u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/flavors/42',
                    u'rel': u'bookmark'
                }
            ]
        },
        'OS-EXT-AZ: availability_zone': u'nova',
        'id': u'7a3a2eab-7d3b-498b-bc69-ba39396ada4f',
        'metadata': {

        }
    }>,
    <Server: {
        'status': u'ACTIVE',
        'OS-EXT-STS: task_state': None,
        'addresses': {
            u'private': [
                {
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS-MAC: mac_addr': u'fa: 16: 3e: 23: 96: d9',
                    u'version': 4,
                    u'addr': u'192.0.0.5',
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS: type': u'fixed'
                },
                {
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS-MAC: mac_addr': u'fa: 16: 3e: 23: 96: d9',
                    u'version': 4,
                    u'addr': u'172.24.4.1',
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS: type': u'floating'
                }
            ]
        },
        'name': u'test1',
        'links': [
            {
                u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/v2/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/servers/1114cb76-f3df-4c60-8b12-5ad14224ffbd',
                u'rel': u'self'
            },
            {
                u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/servers/1114cb76-f3df-4c60-8b12-5ad14224ffbd',
                u'rel': u'bookmark'
            }
        ],
        'created': u'2015-08-01T12: 03: 04Z',
        'key_name': None,
        'image': {
            u'id': u'd983bdc9-9a82-4611-b644-86f9bf53406b',
            u'links': [
                {
                    u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/images/d983bdc9-9a82-4611-b644-86f9bf53406b',
                    u'rel': u'bookmark'
                }
            ]
        },
        'OS-DCF: diskConfig': u'AUTO',
        'image_name': u'cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-uec',
        'OS-EXT-STS: power_state': 1,
        'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR: host': u'localhost.localdomain',
        'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR: instance_name': u'instance-00000004',
        'tenant_id': u'020377f522324546b072af92862e6466',
        'user_id': u'f807d60e53c9454ebe7b38d10d1d1c87',
        'flavor': {
            u'id': u'42',
            u'links': [
                {
                    u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/flavors/42',
                    u'rel': u'bookmark'
                }
            ]
        },
        'OS-EXT-AZ: availability_zone': u'nova',
        'id': u'1114cb76-f3df-4c60-8b12-5ad14224ffbd',
        'metadata': {

        }
    }>,
    <Server: {
        'status': u'ACTIVE',
        'OS-EXT-STS: task_state': None,
        'addresses': {
            u'private': [
                {
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS-MAC: mac_addr': u'fa: 16: 3e: 98: 81: 4c',
                    u'version': 4,
                    u'addr': u'192.0.0.4',
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS: type': u'fixed'
                }
            ]
        },
        'name': u'ce-2',
        'links': [
            {
                u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/v2/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/servers/8b97b82b-a9e4-4fe0-adcb-eeaaac170301',
                u'rel': u'self'
            },
            {
                u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/servers/8b97b82b-a9e4-4fe0-adcb-eeaaac170301',
                u'rel': u'bookmark'
            }
        ],
        'created': u'2015-07-20T11: 25: 44Z',
        'key_name': None,
        'image': {
            u'id': u'd983bdc9-9a82-4611-b644-86f9bf53406b',
            u'links': [
                {
                    u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/images/d983bdc9-9a82-4611-b644-86f9bf53406b',
                    u'rel': u'bookmark'
                }
            ]
        },
        'OS-DCF: diskConfig': u'AUTO',
        'image_name': u'cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-uec',
        'OS-EXT-STS: power_state': 1,
        'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR: host': u'localhost.localdomain',
        'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR: instance_name': u'instance-00000003',
        'tenant_id': u'020377f522324546b072af92862e6466',
        'user_id': u'f807d60e53c9454ebe7b38d10d1d1c87',
        'flavor': {
            u'id': u'42',
            u'links': [
                {
                    u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/flavors/42',
                    u'rel': u'bookmark'
                }
            ]
        },
        'OS-EXT-AZ: availability_zone': u'nova',
        'id': u'8b97b82b-a9e4-4fe0-adcb-eeaaac170301',
        'metadata': {

        }
    }>,
    <Server: {
        'status': u'ACTIVE',
        'OS-EXT-STS: task_state': None,
        'addresses': {
            u'private': [
                {
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS-MAC: mac_addr': u'fa: 16: 3e: 32: db: 57',
                    u'version': 4,
                    u'addr': u'192.0.0.3',
                    u'OS-EXT-IPS: type': u'fixed'
                }
            ]
        },
        'name': u'ce-1',
        'links': [
            {
                u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/v2/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/servers/afaa50ad-8025-415b-81c4-566c8e06f388',
                u'rel': u'self'
            },
            {
                u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/servers/afaa50ad-8025-415b-81c4-566c8e06f388',
                u'rel': u'bookmark'
            }
        ],
        'created': u'2015-07-20T11: 25: 44Z',
        'key_name': None,
        'image': {
            u'id': u'd983bdc9-9a82-4611-b644-86f9bf53406b',
            u'links': [
                {
                    u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/images/d983bdc9-9a82-4611-b644-86f9bf53406b',
                    u'rel': u'bookmark'
                }
            ]
        },
        'OS-DCF: diskConfig': u'AUTO',
        'image_name': u'cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-uec',
        'OS-EXT-STS: power_state': 1,
        'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR: host': u'localhost.localdomain',
        'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR: instance_name': u'instance-00000002',
        'tenant_id': u'020377f522324546b072af92862e6466',
        'user_id': u'f807d60e53c9454ebe7b38d10d1d1c87',
        'flavor': {
            u'id': u'42',
            u'links': [
                {
                    u'href': u'http: //10.0.2.15: 8774/020377f522324546b072af92862e6466/flavors/42',
                    u'rel': u'bookmark'
                }
            ]
        },
        'OS-EXT-AZ: availability_zone': u'nova',
        'id': u'afaa50ad-8025-415b-81c4-566c8e06f388',
        'metadata': {

        }
    }>
],
False)
```

Comment: Provide a stacktrace, please.

Comment: @Neelabh Singh : Kindly check the other question you asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816179/django-create-a-json-for-rest-api/31817055#31817055. You are trying to access the name attribute on a list which is not possible try to access it on the objects inside that list.

Comment: Why not use [Django-REST-Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org)

Answer (score 0):

**I solved my problem**

I got the problem, it was due to `api.nova.server_list(self.request)` returns two value like `([<{server1}>,<{server2}>], False)` But in my code I have written like this `instances=api.nova.server_list(self.request)`. I was not taking care of last return value '**False**'. So it was giving error.

Following code is correct,

```
 instances, more=api.nova.server_list(self.request)
          def serializer(m):
              ret= {} 
              ret['Name']= m.name
              ret['Id']=m.id
              return ret
          context= {
              'instances': [serializer(m) for m in instances],
          }
          return HttpResponse(json.dumps([context]), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: If you are going to make a REST API, I strongly recomment you to try Django REST Framework (DRF) or any other similar mature solution. Hand-made JSON is OK when you are just playing, but with project complication growth, things will run out of control very quick.